# slideToggle() script generation

Tags: javascript, jquery, selector, slidetoggle

I have a script that generates on a div click, as well as all the elements specified in the script. The trouble is, the script is basically copy-and-pasted, but it throws no errors like it doesn't even register.

The only thing I can think of is that `$('.header')` isn't finding the `<span>` that the class `header` is defined in. Am I using this selector wrong?

**JavaScript**

```
html += "<tr><td>Other</td><td>" + stats.others.length + "<span class='header'> (Toggle View)</span></td></tr>";

html += "<tr id='otherResponseList' style='display:none;'><td>Other responses:</td><td><ul>" + otherListHtml + "</ul></td></tr>";

html += "<tr><td>Count total:</td><td>" + stats.total + "</td></tr>";

html += "<script>$('.header').click(function(){$('#otherResponseList')slideToggle(20);});</script>";

$("#countTable tbody").html(html);
```

Comment: At least you should have a dot between `$('#otherResponseList')` and `slideToggle`

Comment: That was it! Thanks a ton.

Answer (score -1):

There was supposed to be a `.` before `slideToggle`. That fixed it.

Updated script: `<script>$('.header').click(function(){$('#otherResponseList').slideToggle(20);});</script>`